# gnuplottex package not working anymore

Tags: texlive, gnuplot, gnuplottex

Whenever I try to use the `gnuplottex` package, I get the following error messages:

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/gnuplottex/gnuplottex.sty:79: Argument of " has an extra }. [...te\write18{rm -f "\jobname.gnuploterrors"}]
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/gnuplottex/gnuplottex.sty:79: Paragraph ended before " was complete. [...te\write18{rm -f "\jobname.gnuploterrors"}]
/home/myDocument.tex:118: Package catchfile Error: File `myDocument.gnuploterrors' not found. [\end{document}]
TeX STOPPED: File ended while scanning use of \gnuploterrors@eatpa\ifx \gnuploterrors@ \@empty \else \PackageWarningNoLine {gnuplottex}
TeX reports the error was in file: myDocument.tex
```

Line 79 of `gnuplottex.sty` reads `\immediate\write18{rm -f "\jobname.gnuploterrors"}`, so it not being executed seems to be the cause for the other errors.

Everything worked fine before, but I upgraded to Xubuntu 16.04 LTS lately, so this may be the cause. I already tried removing gnuplot and TeX Live completly and installing them again, but the error remains.

**Edit:**

I'm using `pdflatex` and Version 0.9.1 of `gnuplottex`. All it needs to produce this error is just a `\usepackage{gnuplottex}`, so for example this document doesn't compile:

```
%!TEX options = "--shell-escape"

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{gnuplottex}


\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

However, I noticed that with this minimal file, only the last 3 lines of the error message from above are shown. All 5 lines are only shown if I also add `\usepackage{ngerman}`.

Comment: Can you add a minimal example of a LaTeX file for testing? Also the version of `gnuplottex` is needed. Are you running `pdflatex` or `lualatex`?

Comment: How do I find out my version of `gnuplottex`?

Comment: Look in the log file: you should find something like `Package: gnuplottex 2015/12/13 v0.9.1 gnuplot graphs in LaTeX`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an oversight of `gnuplottex`: if no `gnuplot` diagram is processed, the file `<jobname>.gnuploterrors` is not produced, so the final code for displaying errors fails to find it.

```
203 \AtEndDocument{%
204   \ifmiktex
205   \else
206     \CatchFileDef\gnuploterrors@{\jobname.gnuploterrors}{\endlinechar=`^^J \catcode`\ =12 }%
207     \expandafter\gnuploterrors@eatpar\gnuploterrors@\@nil
208     \ifx\gnuploterrors@\@empty\else
209       \PackageWarningNoLine{gnuplottex}{Gnuplot execution produced errors:^^J%
210         \detokenize\expandafter{\gnuploterrors@}}%
211     \fi
212   \fi
213 }
```

Lines 206–211 should better be

```
    \IfFileExists{\jobname.gnuploterrors}{%
      \CatchFileDef\gnuploterrors@{\jobname.gnuploterrors}{\endlinechar=`^^J \catcode`\ =12 }%
      \expandafter\gnuploterrors@eatpar\gnuploterrors@\@nil
      \ifx\gnuploterrors@\@empty\else
        \PackageWarningNoLine{gnuplottex}{Gnuplot execution produced errors:^^J%
          \detokenize\expandafter{\gnuploterrors@}}%
      \fi
    }{}%
```

However, the error should not appear as soon as you have a `gnuplot` environment in your document.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Shouldn't this be considered a bug in `gnuplottex`? Also, shouldn't many more people be running in to this problem? I couldnt't find anything about it online.

Comment: @jmb Possibly nobody tried using the package with no `gnuplot` environment in the document. But it's surely something to be solved.

Comment: @jmb It's silly to unaccept the answer that solves the ***stated*** problem. If you have different problems, you should state them clearly.

Comment: Thanks for the fix! @jmb I've just uploaded a new version, which should be available shortly. Please use [the github project page](https://github.com/larskotthoff/gnuplottex/issues) for reporting bugs.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Added to the list of “watched” repositories