# gnuplottex and ngerman

Tags: packages, gnuplot, german, gnuplottex

A while ago, [I asked a question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305957/gnuplottex-package-not-working-anymore) about always occurring errors from the `gnuplottex` package.

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/gnuplottex/gnuplottex.sty:79: Argument of " has an extra }. [...te\write18{rm -f "\jobname.gnuploterrors"}]
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/gnuplottex/gnuplottex.sty:79: Paragraph ended before " was complete. [...te\write18{rm -f "\jobname.gnuploterrors"}]
```

I just noticed my document compiles fine when not I'm not including the `ngerman` package, which I usually do.

Is there any way to use `ngerman` and `gnuplottex` both?

**Edit:**
Here is a minimal example document  producing the error for me:

```
%!TEX options = "--shell-escape"

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{gnuplottex}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

The other question actually  did  mention some error messages disappeared when not including `ngerman`, but apparently, I was to dumb to get that hint. For some reason, *all* errors disappear now. Maybe, the remaining errors in the old question where because of some log file I forgot to delete.

Comment: Please post a document, not only error messages

Comment: Minimal example, please. The other question didn't mention `ngerman` at all.

Comment: Sure! The error already occurs when just including both packages, though.

Comment: well, `ngerman` is quite old and outdated, as far as I know

Comment: Oh, really? Should I use `\usepackage[german]{babel}` instead?

Comment: Yes, you should use `babel`, but with the option `ngerman`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `ngerman` is obsolete and should not be used.

The error disappears if you correctly use `babel`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{gnuplottex}

\begin{document}

\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=epslatex]
plot sin(x) w l
\end{gnuplot}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, but not recommendable, load the packages in reverse order.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{gnuplottex}
\usepackage{ngerman}

\begin{document}

\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=epslatex]
plot sin(x) w l
\end{gnuplot}

\end{document}
```

This fixes the error about `"`. The other one is fixed by *having* a `gnuplot` environment in the document or with the fix suggested for [gnuplottex package not working anymore](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305957/gnuplottex-package-not-working-anymore)

Note that the two issues are completely unrelated to each other.